# Android: Cannot set gravity of TableLayout to Right

Tags: android

I know there are tons of questions about this already floating around SO but I've read a bunch of them and still cannot get my 3rd column to align to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:stretchColumns="2"
 >
  <TableRow>

 <ImageView 
  android:src="@drawable/blue_light" 
  android:layout_height="48px" 
  android:layout_width="48px" 
  android:padding="3dp"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
  android:layout_column="1"/>   

   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_column="2">

   <TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/row_title"  
     android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:textStyle="bold" />
   </TableRow>

   <TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/row_author"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:textColor="#9E9E9E"  
      android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>
   </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

   <TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
   >

   <TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:textColor="#1F9C29" 
     android:textSize="15dp" 
     android:id="@+id/row_txt1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textStyle="bold" />
   </TableRow>

   <View
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    />

   <TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:textColor="#1B27D1" 
     android:id="@+id/row_txt2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textStyle="bold"/>
   </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> cannot get my 3rd column to align to the right.

Off the cuff, I suspect that nested `TableLayout` widgets will not work terribly well. While `TableLayout` was designed to mimic the HTML table "API", there are limits to the analogy.

If you want the "3rd column to align to the right", put everything into the outer `TableLayout`, then try `android:layout_gravity="right"` on all widgets in that column.

Comment: Yup that was it. I moved to using nested LinearLayouts within  the TableLayout to simplify the XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it with the following:

Inside the TableRow attributes add the two following lines:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="right"
```

If you use the Layout_gravity = right, for some reason it does not work at all.
Enjoy, 
Adrian.